# is there a jboss parent maven project for the 6.x release?

Tags: maven-2, jboss

im trying to get familiar with the new JBoss 6 and having a really tough time piecing together all the different sub-projects that comprise it.
basically what i want is to compose the list of maven artifacts that form jboss 6 (6.0.0.M4, to be specific), so i could add them as runtime dependencies to my demo project - that way it would be easy for me to step through jboss source.

i know there is a jar-versions.xml file in the jboss root which specifies the versions, but surely there's some sort of parent pom i could look at ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about what you're looking for exactly. Would [`org.jboss.jbossas:jboss-as-parent:6.0.0.M1:pom`](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/org/jboss/jbossas/jboss-as-parent/6.0.0.M1/jboss-as-parent-6.0.0.M1.pom) help?

Comment: im looking for some "provided"-scoped maven dependency i could add to my project so that my IDE (intelliJ) would automatically download all relevant source code.
this would allow me to debug into JBoss code as well (otherwise tracing into a file for which the IDE has no source code attached gives me decompiled stubs).

thank you.